# Form Input in Bootstrap modal hidden by mobile keyboard

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **web page** that is seen in **mobile devices** too.
This page shows a **modal window** built using **Twitter Bootstrap** that is tall as the average screens (or a bit less).
In the content area of the modal window, quite at the bottom of the content area, an input field wait the user to enter a code.

The issue is that when the user tap into the input field, the virtual keyboard hide the input and it's impossible to see what you are writing there until you'll close the keyboard.

I would like the Modal Window to scroll in order to show the field.

Did you had issues similar? How did you solve them?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos illum eum expedita enim culpa natus qui soluta eaque, error perspiciatis, doloribus, eius? Rerum, placeat sint temporibus voluptatum ad quasi consequuntur!</p>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal active" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus iure quos nam veritatis, qui fugiat at magnam vel recusandae odit tempore, quas repudiandae? Placeat, non! Laboriosam quidem maxime nisi mollitia!</p>
        <p>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="field" />
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/sxgjy2de/

**SCREENSHOT**
[image: Input field hidden by the virtual keyboard]

Comment: please screenshot

Comment: @avrilalejandro here it is

Comment: try `[inputId].onmousedown=function(){this.focus()`

Comment: In the screenshot I'm already focused into the field. But the modal is anchored to the top and the input is not visible...

Comment: `$("#myInput").on("focus", function(){$('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height());/*window.scrollTo(x, y);*/});`

Comment: No, the issue is that usually bootstrap modal window are anchored at the top of the screen and you cannot move up with them.